# Hardware Keyboard is pushing UI components up

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic4

The hardware Keyboard is pushing my UI components up every time the ionic input is focused on.
I changed the **android:windowSoftInputMode** from **adjustResize** to **AdjustPan**, which almost did the job, the only problem is it kind of overlaps the contents, so for me to be able to see the ion cards at the bottom I would have to close the keyboard.
Any suggestions?

```
<activity 
 android:configChanges=
 "orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" 
 android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" 
 android:name="MainActivity" 
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" 
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Comment: Try to put your whole layout into `ScrollView` so you can scroll your view up while keyboard is visible. This works for me.

Comment: I can scroll to see all of the cards in there, but when i get to the last cards at the very bottom , or lets say that there is only one card, the keyboard is taking 50% of the screen, the card is showing, but not 100% of the cards length, there is at least 20% being overlapped by the keyboard

Comment: I can't help you then. In case like this i often use **"next"** `button` on the keyboard to navigate between `EditText`'s, and when there is no more of those the button turns to **"ok"** and I can close keyboard with it. It is normal behaviour of keyboard and it's probably for cases like this one.

Comment: Did you try adding a margin bottom to your layout everytime you open the keyboard then removing it when you close the keyboard ? It should push your elements a little bit to the top. You can achieve this by overriding the onFocusChangedListener of each EditText.

Comment: @Adonis320 No I haven't, I am using ionic 4, and i installed the ionic cordova plugin keyboard. I assumed this plugin does all the work.
The original problem was that the ion content was pushed up  with the keyboard, and when i resolved that issue, it overlaped the ion content. At least 20% of the ion content is overlapped by that keyboard.

Comment: So what you want is to show the whole ion-content and the keyboard at the same time ? If that's the case try changing the ion-content height

Comment: @Adonis320 so I am doing is i have an ion search bar, and I am instant filtering items which are basically ion cards, so if i type C for example i get all the cards that start with C. I can scroll down to the  last card, but when i get to the very bottom i can see around 80% of the card, and as well the admob banner at the buttom isnt there. if i manually close the keyboard its there, but when the keyboard is visible, that lower section is overlapped. My goal is to show both the whole ion content, and the keybpard at the same time. I tried setting the min-height of the ion content but no good.

Comment: I don't think that you should use the min-height but instead change the height of the list itself. So when you click on the search bar you reduce the height of your list so it ends before the keyboard, this way they won't overlap. Consider also reducing it's height even more to show the ad banner too.

Comment: Are you using cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard? If so - try adding <preference name="resizeOnFullScreen" value="true" /> to your config.xml. Also try setting it to false to see what happens.

Comment: @NickyTheWrench it is not working. I found a workaround. Whenever the search bar is focused, I am using the ngstyle to add a margin to the ionic search bar, and resetting it back to normal after. I tested it on one device and it looks decent, I haven't tested it on another device, but I am assuming it should be alright

Answer (score 0):

My work around was the following ( not too perfect, but it did the job):

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

As mentioned earlier, change **adjustResize** to **adjustPan.**

**In my component.ts:**

```
  // method to check if the ion search bar is focused, which means keyboard visible
  checkIsFocused($event){
  if ($event) {
  this.isKeyboardVisible = true;
   } else {
  this.isKeyboardVisible = false;
  }
  }
```

**In the template:**

```
<ion-row class="search-row" [ngStyle]="{'margin':isKeyboardVisible ? '20px 0px 20px 
   0px' : '0px'}">
  <ion-searchbar animated [(ngModel)]="searchText" mode="md" 
  (ionFocus)="checkVisibility($event)">
 </ion-searchbar>
</ion-row>
```

**Note**: I tested it on one device and it was decent, Haven't had the chance to test it on different devices, but I assume it's good.